# Open CV ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, tensorflow

I am new to OpenCV and TensorFlow. I am trying to get a live camera preview and use the live camera feed for TensorFlow prediction. Here is the part of code for live preview and prediction:

```
image = np.zeros((64, 64, 3))
softmax_pred = tf.nn.softmax(conv_net(x, weights, biases, image_size, 1.0))

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret_val, img = cam.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img,1)
    cv2.imshow('my webcam',img)
    img = img.resize((64,64))
    image = array(img).reshape(1,64,64,3)
    image.astype(float)
    result = sess.run(softmax_pred, feed_dict={x: image})
```

I am not sure what's wrong here. I am getting this error:

```
image = array(img).reshape(1,64,64,3)
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

My Tensor placeholder for image has the shape Tensor '(?, 64, 64, 3)'. I did the same for jpeg image by manually loading an image from disk and reshaping that image to (1,64,643) and it works fine.Here is the code for manually loading an image and then predicting:

```
img = Image.open('/home/pragyan/Documents/miniProject/PredictImages/IMG_4804.JPG')
img = img.resize((64, 64))
image = array(img).reshape(1,64,64,3)
image.astype(float)
result = sess.run(softmax_pred, feed_dict={x: image})
```

The above code works but while reshaping a live frame from webcam gives me this error(ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged). Is there a way to fix this? I am not able to understand how to fix it.

Comment: Your `img` has size `64 x 64` (as you resized later), but you try to resize it to `64 x 64 x 3`.

Comment: I am getting this error: im = self.im.resize(size, resample)
TypeError: must be sequence of length 2, not 3

Comment: did you try to use numpy.arrange or numpy.reshape?https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: I get this error while using numpy.reshape : TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: As I have mentioned above the code is working fine for a jpeg image. It's not working when I use a frame from webcam.